# Querying on large data set using Python

Tags: python, sql

I have a Python script hitting Hive for querying data sets.

```
with conn.cursor() as cur:
cur.execute('select * from dm_mx.MMX_CNT_PLAN_PARTITION')
total_partition=cur.fetchall()
```

The output of the sql statement has huge dataset and it is grouped based on country and prod_cd. Now I need to fetch a specific rows based on country and prod_cd and do some manipulations.

`cur.fetchall()` will fetch all the dataset rather than based on a groups. Is there a way to achieve this.

Comment: `cur.fetchall()` just fetches all rows for the given query, if I understand your problem you want to fetch only the rows with a particular country. In this case you have to edit your query by adding something like `WHERE country = <country>`

Comment: the grouping is based on country and prod_id. There are around seven million groups. So I can't hit HIVE seven million times to fetch the data. It is time consuming..

Comment: @Pedru has clearly shown you the answer, your problem isn't `fetchall()`, `fetchone()` or even loop over the cursor. It's how you construct your query to perform GROUP BY and WHERE. If you can't think of the correct query statement, then you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: My sql statement is generic. If I parameterize the sql statement, each and every time I need to hit hive..which is time consuming and performance would degrade..

Comment: Will pandas dataframe help me to have a workaround? i can have the data in csv file.